# Greed in Ruby Koans

Tags: beginner, ruby, programming-challenge, dice

I've finished the greed problem in Ruby Koans after much confusion. This is my first programming language and I have been doing fine, but then this problem really tripped me up for some reason, perhaps because it is one of the first problems where I need to be creating my own method. I eventually came up with this - can you give me your feedback about it?

Is it totally inefficient, whats wrong with it? How would you improve it, and how should I as a novice approach my education - should I settle for the way my mind works right now when I think about problem solving or should I try to understand more complex approaches to the code?

```
def score(dice)
  total = 0
  count = (1..6).each do |n|
  # for each die, make sure we've counted how many occurrencess there are
  die_value = dice.each { |d| d == n }
   # iterate over each, and handle points for singles and triples
  point_totals = die_value.size
  total += 1000 if die_value.size == 3 and d == 1
  total + 1000 + (point_totals - 3)*100 if die_value.size > 3 and d == 1
  total += 500 if die_value.size == 3 and d == 5
  total + 500 + (point_totals - 3)*50 if die_value.size > 3 and d == 5
  end
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749973/ruby-greed-koan-how-can-i-improve-my-if-then-soup

Comment: You appear to be using `+` and `+=` indifferently. Keep in mind `x + y` doesn't necessarily do anything unless you assign that result to something.

Comment: basically you've got the right ideas, but check your syntax.  Perhaps try writing bits at a time, run to confirm it works as expected, and then add more.  These "bits" can be from dividing and conquering the problem into sub-problems; for example: 1) Frequency hash   2) handle ones  3) handle fives  4) handle the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is broken, since it doesn't pass the koan's test suite. It doesn't do what it's supposed to do. We typically don't review broken code on CodeReview, but I'll give it a go regardless (since the alternative would probably be to move it *back* to SO from whence it came).

First, as tadman pointed out in the comments, `+` is not the same as `+=`. So two of your lines don't do anything at all, because you're just adding some numbers, but you're not storing the result anywhere.

Secondly, `die_value` ends up being the same as `dice`. The `each` iterator doesn't do anything to the `dice` array; it doesn't filter or transform it in any way. It does some comparisons along the way, but they don't have any impact on anything.

You also don't use `point_totals` for anything.

And you store the result of the `(1..6).each` expression in `count`, which is what gets returned. But, as mentioned above, `each` doesn't really do anything to the array (or range, in this case), that you call it on. So your method *always* returns the range. It simply doesn't return a score at all.

So once we remove those pointless lines, we get this, which is equivalent to your code:

```
def score(dice)
  1..6
end
```

That's obviously not right. Let's at least get closer by returning the `total` instead:

```
def score(dice)
  total = 0
  (1..6).each do |n| # no need for the count variable
    total += 1000 if dice.size == 3 and d == 1
    total += 500 if dice.size == 3 and d == 5
  end
  total
end
```

But that's obviously not right either, and does indeed fail the koan's built-in tests. It doesn't handle single 1s and 5s, and it can't handle triples of values other than 1 or 5, and it can't handle *multiple* triples of any kind.

What you're probably looking for is the `select` method, which *does* filter the array you call it on:

```
n = 2 # as an example

[1,2,2,3].each { |d| d == n }   # => [1,2,2,3] (no change)
[1,2,2,3].select { |d| d == n } # => [2,2] (filtered)
```

You'll also want to take a look at [`reduce`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) which is a cleaner option than declaring `total = 0`, and modifying it from within an `each` block. Basically, you don't want code to have side-effects; that is, to modify things outside its immediate environment.

And there's `group_by` which could make the dice-counting simpler.

```
dice = [1, 2, 3, 2] # an example
groups = dice.group_by { |value| value } # => {1: [1], 2: [2,2], 3: [3]}
```

Now there's no need to loop through all the `1..6` values, when we can instead look at what dice value are actually present.

By the way, the above can be shortened to `dice.group_by(&:to_i)` (i.e. group by the result of calling `to_i` on each item in the array).

Also, what if the dice values you get are seven 1s? That's *two* triples and one single value (2 * 1000 + 1 * 100 = 2100 points), but your approach (if it had any impact in your code, which it doesn't) only really checks for *one* triple, and treats what remains as singles. So it would arrive at a score of 1 * 1000 + 4 * 100 = 1400.
So you need check *how many* triples there are, not just check for one.

Taking the above, we can use `reduce` to figure out the score

```
def score(dice)
  dice.group_by(&:to_i).reduce(0) do |score, (value, dice)|
    triples, singles = dice.count.divmod(3) # get the number of triples and singles, i.e. integer division and remainder
    if value == 1
      score += 1000 * triples + 100 * singles
    else
      score += 100 * value * triples
      score += 50 * singles if value == 5
    end
    score
  end
end
```

We can further simplify that if we use the fact that the scores for triples/singles of 1 are basically 10x the scores for anything else. So instead of the if-else branches, we can do this:

```
def score(dice)
  dice.group_by(&:to_i).reduce(0) do |score, (value, dice)|
    value = 10 if value == 1 # if value is 1, exchange it for 10
    triples, singles = dice.count.divmod(3)
    score += 10 * singles * value if value % 5 == 0 # only multiples of 5 (aka 5 and 10) award points for singles
    score += 100 * triples * value # all values award points for triples
  end
end
```